# Python Phone Number Pattern Matching w/ RegEx (findall)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to match to a [NANP standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers#United_States,_Canada,_and_other_NANP_countries) 10-digit phone number with some using – as a separator (e.g. 123-456-7890) and some will have a dot (.) as a separator (e.g. 123.456.7890).

I have tried:

```
numbers = "123-456-7890, 123.456.7890"
phones = re.findall("\d{3}*\D*\d{3}*\D*\d{4}", numbers)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex)

Comment: If you want to force the same separator by [capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html): [`\d{3}([.-])\d{3}\1\d{4}`](https://regex101.com/r/HuBge3/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
result = re.findall('\d{3}[-.]\d{3}[-.]\d{4}', numbers)
print(result)
```

Output: `['123-456-7890', '123.456.7890']`

- `[-.]` : match only `-` or `.`
- `\d{3}` : **`three`** times match any digit `(0-9)`